# Preventing the SearchView from collapsing

Tags: java, android

I have a `SearchView` in my action-bar. When the user searches, I invoke my `AsyncTask` to begin fetching the data but after the data is retuned, the `SearchView`collapses.

Here's my code that creates the search widget:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.search, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    if (this.objAdapter == null) {
        searchView.setIconified(false);
        searchView.requestFocusFromTouch();
    }

    return true;

}
```

I'd to prevent the user from collapsing the `SearchView`. I'd the search string to be visible at all times.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [search view example](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/action-bar-search-view/).

For your case, use Action Flag- SHOW_AS_ACTION_WITH_TEXT

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

On SearchView instance you need to call:

```
searchView.setIconified(false)
searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onClose() {
    return true; //returning true will stop search view from being collapsed 
  }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Set the `iconifiedByDefault` attribute to `false`.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html

Comment: set iconifiedByDefault = false, only makes searchViews stay already open, but still possible click to close